# Re-order based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have an array of dicts where there are the keys `name`, and `val`.
I have another array of *array* where there are always two values: `src_XX` and `dst_XX` where `XX` are integers.

I want to sort the first array of dicts using the `name` and the position its value in the other array (of arrays)

```
s = [{'name': 'src_0', 'val': 0},
     {'name': 'src_1', 'val': 1},
     {'name': 'src_2', 'val': 2},
     {'name': 'src_3', 'val': 3},
     {'name': 'src_4', 'val': 4},
     {'name': 'src_5', 'val': 5},]
u= [['src_1', 'dst_2'],
     ['src_0', 'dst_0'],
     ['dst_1', 'src_2'],
     ['dst_3', 'src_3'],
     ['src_4', 'dst_4'],
     ['src_5', 'dst_5'],]
```

the final result should be:

```
s = [{'name': 'src_1', 'val': 1},
     {'name': 'src_0', 'val': 0},
     {'name': 'src_2', 'val': 2},
     {'name': 'src_3', 'val': 3},
     {'name': 'src_4', 'val': 4},
     {'name': 'src_5', 'val': 5},]
```

I've already tried many things and one is working but it's very ugly, not optimized and not Python-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would create a simpler reference array using this:

```
reference = [sorted(x)[1] for x in u]

>>> ['src_1', 'src_0', 'src_2', 'src_3', 'src_4', 'src_5']
```

Then sort `s` like so:

```
s.sort(key=lambda x: reference.index(x['name']))

>>> [{'name': 'src_1', 'val': 1},
     {'name': 'src_0', 'val': 0},
     {'name': 'src_2', 'val': 2},
     {'name': 'src_3', 'val': 3},
     {'name': 'src_4', 'val': 4},
     {'name': 'src_5', 'val': 5}]
```

Comment: This is working! The only problem is that I need to extract those keys twice: once for the `dst` field and once again for the `src` (to make it simpler, my question was only about `src`). I tried to find a way using your code and make a one-liner like `ref_dst, ref_src = [a[0], a[1] for a in [sorted(x) for x in u]]` but this doesn't work. Any idea maybe?

Comment: I think this does what you want: `ref_dst, ref_src = [[sorted(x)[y] for x in u] for y in [0, 1]]`